# Convert UI file to Python Using pyuic4 Issue

Tags: user-interface, pyqt4, pyuic

I'm trying to convert a ui file to python using pyuic4 but I get "The system cannot find the path specified".  (`pyuic4 Mainwindow.ui > MainWindow.py`)  I'm not sure why since I've given the command line the exact location of the file (pyuic4) in Anaconda.  If I use pyuic5 it does the conversion without a problem (`pyuic5 Mainwindow.ui > MainWindow.py`). I'm using Windows with Anaconda3. Anyone have any ideas what the problem might be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just ran into this myself.  It looks like the Anaconda build has an issue.  pyuic4.bat has some machine dependent paths that need to be changed to match your system.

**Original pyuic4.bat text** (Notice the path)

```
@"C:\aroot\stage\python" "C:\aroot\stage\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

**Correct Anaconda text:**

```
@"C:\Anaconda\python" "C:\Anaconda\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```

**Correct Anaconda3 text:**

```
@"C:\Anaconda3\python" "C:\Anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\pyuic.py" %1 %2 %3 %4 %5 %6 %7 %8 %9
```